# How to change Signup form in Django Rest Framework and Django allauth?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm building an API with Django Rest framework, where Django Allauth is responsible for my signup registration. After implementing everything works fine:
[image: Signup Form]

On this Signup Form, I want to remove the Username field and replace it for an Age field. I know that, to achieve that, I need to config ACCOUNT_FORMS, But how should I create this form?

```
# settings.py

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    "signup": "user.forms.MyCustomSignupForm",
}

# models.py

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


# forms.py

from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a custom signup form for allauth which only requires an email address.

My form looks like this;

```py
# settings.py
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'accounts.forms.SignupForm',
}
```

```py
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _

from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm as BaseSignupForm


class SignupForm(BaseSignupForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'type': 'email',
                'placeholder': _('E-mail address')
            }
        )
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if settings.SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE:
            self.fields["email2"] = forms.EmailField(
                label=_("E-mail (again)"),
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                    attrs={
                        'type': 'email',
                        'placeholder': _('E-mail address confirmation')
                    }
                )
            )

        self.fields['email'].label = ugettext("E-mail")
        self.fields['email'].required = True

        to_remove = [
            'username',
            'password1',
            'password2'  # ignored when not present
        ]
        for field in to_remove:
            if field in self.fields:
                del self.fields[field]
```

So you could do something like this, and just add your `age` field.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks a lot for your response.

In order to test it, I just copy your code into my django app. But it seems that I still get the same fields in Django Rest Framework Register page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> On this Signup Form, I want to remove the Username field and replace
> it for an Age field. I know that, to achieve that, I need to config
> ACCOUNT_FORMS, But how should I create this form?

Creating a new signup form won't change anything. You don't need to create a signup form here to change the required fields in signup. You need to make changes in your user model and in your settings.

Register your required fields in `REQUIRED_FIELDS` as below.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # email is added to this list automatically
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'age'] 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and you need to make required changes in your `settings.py` well, example:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = True
```

You can change your options according to your needs..
Now the registration form will have 5 fields: email, name, age, password1, password2.

Then you can create your own signup form by overriding the allauth's Signup form to add autofocus or to update widgets etc.

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm as allauth_SignupForm
    
class SignupForm(allauth_SignupForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update(
                {"autofocus": "autofocus", "class": "form-control"})
```